# Display icon for atom feed in Google Reader

Tags: web, favicon, atom-feed, rss-reader, google-reader

Google Reader does not display the icon for my Atom feed [http://feeds.feedburner.com/CartesianClosedComic](https://web.archive.org/web/20160311222649/http://feeds.feedburner.com/CartesianClosedComic).

Here's what I tried, based on various suggestions found on the internet:

- Added an `<icon>` element that points to a png icon. (I also tried an `.ico` icon there.) IMO, this by itself should be sufficient, but for some reason it isn't.
- Added a `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />` element pointing to an `.ico` icon, by analogy with ordinary pages.
- Added a `<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" />` element pointing to a webpage that has a favicon.

None of the above helped.

I also found a hypothesis that one should have a favicon under the domain's root path (something like `http://example.com/favicon.ico`), but that's not an option for me.

Comment: [Google shut down reader on July 1, 2013](https://googleblog.blogspot.com/2013/03/a-second-spring-of-cleaning.html), this question is now useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Reader uses URLs of the form `http://s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicon?domain_url=http://domainname/foo/bar/baz.html` to cache site favicons. I have verified that their cache service makes *a single request* to fetch `http://domainname/favicon.ico` and nothing more; it does not matter if you provide a URL for a specific page — that page never gets requested, so any favicon specified within it will *not* be taken into account.

The bad news is that the only way to affect that favicon cache service is to actually serve a favicon for the `/favicon.ico` URL. The good news is that you don't have to serve an actual Windows Icon file at that URL; a PNG image located at that URL works just fine.

If you're unable to host an actual `/favicon.ico` file on your server, you might be able to set up some sort of redirection or URL rewriting in order to provide a favicon hosted somewhere else. I have tested it and can confirm that Google *will* follow redirects, even to off-site URLs, so you don't even have to host the favicon on the same domain. Still, more bad news: Google does not bother to send an `User-Agent` header with that request, so you cannot set up a conditional redirect only for their favicon cache. All requests in my tests came from the `74.125.18.0/24` network, so you might be able to implement a conditional redirect based on that.

I see that you're hosting your feed content in a `/ccc` subdirectory on your site, and you're probably unwilling to place your comic's favicon as your site-wide favicon. I also see that your hosting provider offers at least 10 subdomains (I have no idea which package you're using, but that's for their lowest offering), so you could create a subdomain on your site (say, `ccc.ro-che.info`) and use that as the URL of your feed. Google will try to fetch `http://ccc.ro-che.info/favicon.ico` for the feed and you can set up a specific favicon resource only on that subdomain. You can also set up a redirect from `http://ccc.ro-che.info/*` to `http://ro-che.info/ccc/*`, so that your comic remains at its present position, and everybody coming from a feed link will also be redirected to the current location of the resource.

Comment: In `http://s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicon?domain_url=http://domainname/foo/bar/baz.html`, how is the `http://domainname/foo/bar/baz.html` part determined? Is it the `rel=alternate` link of the feed?

Comment: Apparently, yes. Tried with `<link>http://domainname/</link>` (was disregarded) and with `<link href="http://domainname/" rel="alternate" type="text/html" />` (was followed, and the favicon was fetched).

Comment: Ok, I made `http://ccc.ro-che.info/favicon.ico` to work, but `http://s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain=ccc.ro-che.info&alt=feed` still shows the standard icon. I guess I just have to wait for the cache to expire — or perhaps there's some way to force it?

Comment: You probably accessed `http://s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain=ccc.ro-che.info&alt=feed` before you placed the favicon online, so its non-existence got cached. The _cached_ default icon indicates clients should cache it until November 4th (one week); hopefully it will refresh your favicon before that date, but if it doesn't, you might try to change the subdomain you link your feed to; just make sure your favicon is online _before_ you try to access it through `googleusercontent.com`.